# how to backup table include sequence in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm using pgAdmin III.
I create an table in postgresql like this
The first I create a sequence auto increment

```
CREATE SEQUENCE iosdevices_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE iosdevices_seq
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The second I create a table with sequence above

```
CREATE TABLE iosdevices
(
  deviceno bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('iosdevices_seq'::regclass),
  userno integer NOT NULL,
  timezoneoffset integer NOT NULL
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE board_iosdevices
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

But when I backup and restore database, the table contain sequence will fail. Other table not contain Success.

Is there any way to backup table and sequence in pgAdmin III?

Comment: What options are you using with pg_dump?

Comment: #1: Blobs+ Only Schema